# Creating a Menu Script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a menu script that will execute a command when the option is selected. This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Please enter you choice: '
options=("Option 1 - File Directory?" "Option 2 - Run MyScript?" "Option 3 - ?" "4 - Quit")
Select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
       case $opt in
            "Option 1 - File Directory?")
                echo "you chose option 1"
                ;;
            "Option 2 - Run MyScript?")
                echo "you chose option 2"
                ;;
            "Option 3 - ?")
                echo "you chose option 3"
                ;;
            "Quit")
                break
                ;;
            *) echo invalid option;;
         esac
done
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: change `Select` to `select` and `"Quit"` to `"4 - Quit"` or otherwise

Comment: I need to get the script to display the current directory if option 1 is selected and also to run a shell script that I created if option 2 is selected. How do I do that and/or what are the commands?

Comment: `echo $PWD` to print current directory, `path_to_the_script` to run a script

Answer (score 1):

Change `Select` to `select` and `"Quit"` to `"4 - Quit"` inside `case` or otherwise.

Your code edited:

```
PS3='Please enter you choice: '
options=("File Directory?" "Run MyScript?" "?" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
       case $opt in
            "File Directory?")
                echo "you chose option 1"
                ;;
            "Run MyScript?")
                echo "you chose option 2"
                ;;
            "?")
                echo "you chose option 3"
                ;;
            "Quit")
                break
                ;;
            *) echo invalid option;;
         esac
done
```

You can check for errors in your shell script [with shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/).